# Is there a list of large-scale, free datasets with psychological variables?

Tags: measurement, methodology, data

Psychologists are not using large, existing, free data to its potential. We don't know what exists, what it contains, or how to use it without a huge investment. Secondary analysis of large, open datasets can improve replicability and reproducibility over small new studies, e.g., through accessibility, high power, generalizability, and validated measures. Between-subjects moderation designs particularly lack power. However, these resources are underused in research and education. Student research often has low inference quality, and educators may lack access to use these tools for pedagogy.

Is there a list of large-scale, free datasets with psychological variables? Additionally, is there a list of other such lists?

Related: [Psychological journal that focuses on publishing interesting psychological datasets](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/3933/psychological-journal-that-focuses-on-publishing-interesting-psychological-datas?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Participants at the [last meeting](https://www.improvingpsych.org) of the Society for the Improvement of Psychological Science developed a list of >100 such datasets with some metadata such as topic, country, total number of participants, etc. The list is currently a collaborative wiki open to editing by anyone.

## [List of open psychology datasets and aggregators](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ejOJTNTL5ApCuGTUciV0REEEAqvhI2Rd2FCoj7afops/edit#gid=0)

Outside of psychology, there are a vast amount of aggregators. Here are two major resources:

https://www.quora.com/Data/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public

https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch

Answer (score 3):

Here this question on the psychology & neuro exchange has several cognitive test datasets.

[Online data repository of research in the cognitive sciences](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16/online-data-repository-of-research-in-the-cognitive-sciences)